# How to show the result of written strings

Tags: c

I'm learning C Programming and I can't resolve this issue.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int first;
    printf("Write Down Your First Name!\n\n");
    scanf("%s", &first);
    int last;
    printf("\nNow Write Your Sir Name!\n\n");
    scanf("%s", &last);
    printf("\nYour Full Name is %s\n\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And I want to show the full name written.

Should I use `void`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `char first[50]` instead of `int` to store a string, same for `last`, also `printf("\nYour Full Name is %s\n\n");` should be `printf("\nYour Full Name is %s %s\n\n", first, last);`

Comment: You should read a good C book before you do anything.

Comment: You seems to have skipped the first few chapters of your beginners book. Or not read one at all, and are just guessing about things. Which is not how you learn programming (well, *educated* guesses are okay, once you *already now the basics*, which you don't seem to do).

Comment: Firstly, you are scanning characters into `int` array. Change that to `char` as mentioned in the first comment. Also In your Last statement, you didn't pass any argument to `printf()`. Pass the arrays with a space between them using `strcat(char *, char *)`.

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin There is no `int` array in the code, and `strcat` is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Why is it not a Good idea? Please explain.

Comment: Thanks @KeineLust, that worked. "machine_1" I surely will do read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first` and `last` should be of `char array` type instead of `int` type if you want to store characters into that.

`int first;` ---> `char first[100]; /* define how many char you want in first*/`

similarly

`int last;` --> `char last[100];`

And while scanning it you don't have to pass `&`

```
scanf("%s", first);
scanf("%s", last);
```

Want to print/show ?

```
printf("\nNow Write Your Sir Name! %s n\n", first);/* you missed to pass argument to printf */
printf("\nYour Full Name is %s\n\n",first);
```

How to join both ? Iterate `last` upto `'\0'` char and copy each char of `last` to end of `first`

```
int len = strlen(first);
first[len] = ' ';/* if needed, put space at the end of first */
for( i = 0, j = len + 1 ; last[i]!='\0;i++,j++) {
     first[j] = last[i]; /* first should have enough space */
}
first[j] = '\0';
```

Now print it as

```
printf("\nYour Full Name is %s\n\n",first);
```